# Serialization issues

Tags: java, serialization

```
public void writeObject(String outFile) {
     try {
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
         Student[] copy = this.getStudents();
         for (Student st : copy){     
             oos.writeObject(st);}
        oos.close();
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
     }

 }
```

The code above is the function I use to serialize the contents of my repository,`getStudens()` is returning an array of my data.

```
public void readSerialized(String fileName) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    while(fis.available()>0){
     ctrl.addC((Student) ois.readObject());}
    ois.close();
    }
```

This my deserialization function which should recreate my data and add it again in my repository.The problem is that it doesn't recreate the data I had in my repository when I serialized it first.
What I had in repository before serialization:

```
1 a 4.0 6.0
2 b 10.0 10.0
3 c 2.0 2.0
4 d 8.0 2.0
5 e 6.0 2.0
```

What the deserialization returns:

```
0  3.0
0  5.0
```

Does this means that my serialization function isn't correct or something goes wrong when I deserialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is needlessly complicated and using available() is always rather confusing I find.  It means you can read *without a system call* it doesn't mean there is nothing left.

I suggest just serializing the array.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(this.getStudents());
oos.close();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
Student[] copy = (Student[]) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

In Java, arrays are objects too.

Comment: Tryed this,but when I'm printing on the screen again,it doesnt shows me the strings `a` ,`b` and so on,only the numbers

Comment: My guess is you are trying to print the `String[]` which should look something like `[String@7ef27456`  This is nothing to do with serialization but the fact the array.toString() is pretty useless.  I suggest printing `Arrays.toString(copy)`

Comment: It means you can read without blocking. It could mean two system calls instead of one.